# Create SAMBA node trust relationship to Windows 2003 PDC server

Tags: windows-server-2003, samba, domain-controller, openvms

I am having problems creating a trust relationship
between an OpenVMS/IA64 node running V/IA64 8.3-1H1,
TCPIP 5.6 ECO 5, CIFS 1.1 ECO1 PS11 (SAMBA 3.0.28a)
and  Windows 2003 server running as a PDC.

I do have two other OpenVMS/Alpha nodes running V/A 8.3,
TCPIP 5.6 ECO 4, CIS 1.1 ECO1 PS10 (SAMBA 3.0.28a)
with working trust relationships to the same Windows 2003 server.

Looking for assistance in resolving the trust "handshake".

```
              \\
```

Details from failing node.

Unless otherwise noted, corresponding files on working nodes
are similar or identical.

SMB.CONF extract:

[global]
        server string = Samba %v running on %h (OpenVMS)
        workgroup = WILMA
        netbios name = %h
        security = DOMAIN
        encrypt passwords = Yes
        name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
        Password server = *
        log file = /samba$log/log.%m
        printcap name = /sys$manager/ucx$printcap.dat
        guest account = DYMAX
        print command = print %f/queue=%p/delete/passall/name="""""%s"""""
        lprm command = delete/entry=%j
        map archive = No
        printing = OpenVMS

net rpc testjoin
[2010/08/13 16:09:28, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.RPC_CLIENT]CLI_PIPE.C;1:(2443)
  get_schannel_session_key: could not fetch trust account password for domain 'WILMA'
[2010/08/13 16:09:28, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.UTILS]NET_RPC_JOIN.C;1:(72)
  net_rpc_join_ok: failed to get schannel session key from server W2K3AD2 for domain WILMA. Error was

NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_I
NFO
Join to domain 'WILMA' is not valid

net rpc join "-Uaccount%password" 
tdb_open_isam: error verifying status of file SAMBA$ROOT:[PRIVATE]secrets.tdb
tdb_open_isam: errno value = 1
[2010/08/13 16:21:13, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.PASSDB]SECRETS.C;1:(72)
  Failed to open /SAMBA$ROOT/PRIVATE/secrets.tdb
[2010/08/13 16:21:13, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.UTILS]NET_RPC.C;1:(322)
  error storing domain sid for WILMA
tdb_open_isam: error verifying status of file SAMBA$ROOT:[PRIVATE]secrets.tdb
tdb_open_isam: errno value = 1
[2010/08/13 16:21:13, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.PASSDB]SECRETS.C;1:(72)
  Failed to open /SAMBA$ROOT/PRIVATE/secrets.tdb
[2010/08/13 16:21:13, 0] SAMBA$SRC:[SOURCE.UTILS]NET_RPC_JOIN.C;1:(409)
  error storing domain sid for WILMA
Unable to join domain WILMA.

```
   \\
```

Example from other node:

net rpc testjoin
Join to 'WILMA' is OK

Answer (score 1):

Execution of the NET JOIN from OpenVMS "SYSTEM" account rather than other privileged account resolved errors.